# FIXED How do i install Xacro for ROS2 humble

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble

I have installed ROS2 Humble and I need to install something called Xacro but i cant find any info anywhere on how and when i try to run `sudo apt install ros-humble-xacro` it doesn't work which i don't even know if the command is correct. I'm very very new to ROS and i was following a tutorial and they told me to install Xacro but i don't know how. I tried searching on youtube and on google but had no luck finding anything. I was following this tutorial at the timestamp 2:12 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcjHyhV0kIs&list=PLunhqkrRNRhYAffV8JDiFOatQXuU-NnxT&index=2&t=190s Any help?  **It seems that running `sudo apt-get update` before the `sudo apt install ros-humble-xacro` recommended by @ssarkar worked and it seems to be installed and i will test it. Thank you for now!**

Comment: It would help us diagnose the problem better if you copy over the error log you receive when you do `sudo apt install ros-humble-xacro`. Also, have you tried running `sudo apt-get update` first?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that running `sudo apt-get update` before the `sudo apt install ros-humble-xacro` recommended by @ssarkar worked and it seems to be installed and i will test it. Thank you for now!